# How to resolve a Field nested in another Type using Graphene GraphQL?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have 3 files: `authors.py`, `posts.py` and `schema.py`.

Posts have one Author and the Query is built in the schema file.

I'm trying to resolve `Author` from inside `Post` without declaring a resolver function in `Post`, since `Author` already has a resolver function for itself declared. The following code works, but I have to reference `resolve_author` from inside the `Post` type and it doesn't seem right. I think Graphene should pass the `parent` param directly to `Author`, no?

If I don't set a resolver for `author` in the `Post` type, it simply returns `null`.

**schema.py**

```py
import graphene
from graphql_api import posts, authors


class Query(posts.Query, authors.Query):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

**authors.py**

```py
from graphene import ObjectType, String, Field


class Author(ObjectType):
    id = ID()
    name = String()


class Query(ObjectType):
    author = Field(Author)

    def resolve_author(parent, info):
        return {
            'id': '123',
            'name': 'Grizzly Bear',
            'avatar': '#984321'
        }
```

**posts.py**

```py
from graphene import ObjectType, String, Field
from graphql_api import authors


class Post(ObjectType):
    content = String()
    author = Field(authors.Author)

    def resolve_author(parent, info):
        # I'm doing like this and it works, but it seems wrong. 
        # I think Graphene should be able to use my resolver 
        # from the Author automatically...
        return authors.Query.resolve_author(parent,
                                            info, id=parent['authorId'])


class Query(ObjectType):
    post = Field(Post)

    def resolve_post(parent, info):
        return {
            'content': 'A title',
            'authorId': '123',
        }
```

Comment: I have the same issue . it works fine in local but in live server it shows  post not found in resolver error. . schema is type User{ id:Int  firstname:string lastname:string post:Post }

Answer (score 2):

`Query.resolve_author` wouldn't be called because there is no relation between it and `Post` object.

I suggest something like:

```py
from graphene import ObjectType, String, Field
from graphql_api import authors


class Post(ObjectType):
    content = String()
    author = Field(authors.Author)

    def resolve_author(self, info):
        # author_utils.get_author returns complete object that will be passed into Author's object resolvers (if some fields are missing)
        # I suggest returning here an object from database so author resolver would extract another fields inside
        # But it may be just an id that will be passed in Author resolvers as first arguments
        return author_utils.get_author(post_id=self.id)


class Query(ObjectType):
    post = Field(Post)

    def resolve_post(parent, info):
        # Here you shouldn't author_id as it's not defined in type 
        return {
            'content': 'A title',
        }
```

And `Author` (assume `author_utils.get_author` just returns an id):

```py
class Author(ObjectType):
    id = ID()
    name = String()

    def resolve_id(id, info):
        # root here is what resolve_author returned in post. Be careful, it also will be called if id is missing after Query.resolve_author
        return id

    def resolve_name(id, info):
        # same as resolve_id
        return utils.get_name_by_id(id)
```

Comment: It is not very efficient this way, I have to fetch the post and then fetch the post again to get the author. There is no problem in return `author_id` from the Field resolver, because it will be filtered by the edge resolvers. You are right that there is no relationship between Post and Author, so I shouldn't expect Post to fetch Author automatically, but there should be a better approach to this...

Comment: I worked with django orm and the best approach I found is fetching all data I have to resolve in the root resolver (there is great lib for this - `graphene-django-optimizer`) and then passing this data to resolvers, so they get complete object and don't have to access db. Related fields (as `Author` of the `Post`) are already fetched in root resolver and only things I have to do is mapping db-fields into `graphql` type.

Comment: That makes sense. I tried something here, I will update this thread after I try it out.